# How to print a char array held by a structure variable?

Tags: c, printf

I have a trouble with this little code which gets two players nickname, name, age, etc ... using a structure variable.

The problem is that when I print the information of both the players, I get some random letters and question marks.

Here's my main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
  Player joueur[2];
  int i = 0;

  do
    {
      printf("Nickname : ");
      scanf("%16s", joueur[i].nickname);

      printf("Last Name : ");
      scanf("%41s", joueur[i].lastName);

      printf("First Name : ");
      scanf("%41s", joueur[i].firstName);

      printf("Your age : ");
      scanf("%d", &joueur[i].age);

      printf("\n");

      i++;
    }while (i < 2);

  int p = 1;
  do
    {
      printf("============== Joueur %d =============\n", p);

      printf("Nickname : %s\n", joueur[i].nickname);
      printf("Name : %s %s\n", joueur[i].lastName, joueur[i].firstName);
      printf("Age : %d\n\n", joueur[i].age);

      p++;
    }while (p < i + 1);

  return (0);
}
```

And the main.h I use with it :

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

typedef struct Player Player;
struct Player 
{
  char nickname[17];
  char firstName[42];
  char lastName[42];

  int age;
};

#endif
```

So far I have not figured out why I don't have the result I expect, and I think I need some help.

Comment: are you having null-termination issues?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It would seem so.

Comment: @erip It appears actually it's something else. :)

Comment: You are using `scanf()` almost right, just need to check it's return value.

Comment: the format specifier: `%s`  (regardless of the max characters modifier) stops on any white space.   Then the next call to scanf() only sees white space and inputs nothing.   To fix that problem, modify the format strings to contain a leading space, similar to: `scanf(" %41s", joueur[i].lastName);`

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`). You should take time to learn how to use your debugger. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) has a good documentation, including a tutorial

Comment: Better have string fields whose size are multiple of 4 (i.e. `sizeof(int)`) bytes. So `char nickname[20];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your printing case,

```
  printf("Nickname : %s\n", joueur[i].nickname);
  printf("Name : %s %s\n", joueur[i].lastName, joueur[i].firstName);
  printf("Age : %d\n\n", joueur[i].age);
```

the `i` value starts from 2, which is well out of bound.

Also, I did not get the purpose of using `p`, at all.

**Solution:** Simply reset `i` to 0 after scanning is complete and use the same condition for printing which you've used for scanning the values. That's all.